# How to pass Ctrl+Enter command to Process when using C# StandardInput redirection

Tags: c#, process, cmd, command-line-arguments, pos-tagger

Im trying to make C# application that uses  [hunpos tagger](https://code.google.com/p/hunpos/).
Runing hunpos-tag.exe requires three input arguments: model, inputFile, outputFile

In cmd it would look something like this:

```
hunpos-tag.exe model <inputFile >outputFile
```

Although, hunpos-tag.exe can be run with just the model, at that point it'll wait for text input (from cmd) which is processed when the tagger receives Ctrl+Enter as input and the results are displayed through standard output. I've been trying to  use StandardInput redirection in C# but I don't know how to send the Ctrl+Enter end command (Or if the redirection works at all). The code:

```
string inputFilePath = path + "\\CopyFolder\\rr";
string pathToExe = path + "\\CopyFolder\\hunpos-tag.exe";

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
   FileName = pathToExe,
   UseShellExecute = false,
   RedirectStandardInput = true,
   WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(pathToExe),
   Arguments = path + "\\CopyFolder\\model.hunpos.mte5.defnpout",
};
try
{
   Process _proc = new Process();
   _proc.StartInfo.FileName = pathToExe;
   _proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   _proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
   _proc.StartInfo.Arguments = path + "\\CopyFolder\\model.hunpos.mte5.defnpout";
    _proc.Start();
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(inputFilePath);
    _proc.StandardInput.Write(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
    _proc.StandardInput.Flush();
    _proc.StandardInput.Close();
    _proc.WaitForExit();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

When I run the following code the tagger has the following output:

```
model loaded
tagger compiled
Fatal error: exception Sys_error("Bad file description")
```

The exception is caused by the .Close() command. The file is valid and works when runned from cmd. Any ideas on how could I send the end command or how to emulate cmd command without using redirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldn't work with input redirection so I managed it with running cmd procces and passing it the required command.

```
        using (Process process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
            process.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "cmd.exe");

            // Redirects the standard input so that commands can be sent to the shell.
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            // Runs the specified command and exits the shell immediately.
            //process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c ""dir""";

            process.OutputDataReceived += ProcessOutputDataHandler;
            process.ErrorDataReceived += ProcessErrorDataHandler;

            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            // Send a directory command and an exit command to the shell
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(path + "\\CopyFolder\\hunpos-tag.exe " + path + "\\CopyFolder\\model.hunpos.mte5.defnpout <" + path + "\\CopyFolder\\rr >" + path + "\\CopyFolder\\zz");
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");

            process.WaitForExit();
        }
```